# Using scaled images or using same image everywhere?

Tags: seo, images

I have an image lets say 300px*300px

I am using 3 different sizes of it on my site 100px*100px, 200px*200px, 300px*300px.

What will be the best for SEO.

Using same images everywhere or using 3 images with different sizes.

Comment: Do you have just one image (of different sizes), or do you have multiple images, as in an image gallery?

Comment: one image of different size and on one page only single size image is shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a single image would be better. By doing this, user's browser will be able to download it only once, cache it and use it on your entire website. Since site speed is one of the signals for site quality, it should help you a little bit. Don't forget to specify alt-attributes for your images, they can be different in different parts of your site, even for the same image.

Comment: This isn't necessarily correct. If you had a page of 100px x 100px thumbnails it would not be correct to only store the larger 300px x 300px image. But this is not clear from the question. "using same images everywhere" implies there is more than one.

Comment: Also worth noting that scaling images with HTML/CSS can itself negatively impact page load speed.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should create different sizes of the image. There are two good reasons for this:

- You are at the mercy of the browser as to how images are rendered, and every browser seems to have their [own choice of algorithms](http://entropymine.com/resamplescope/notes/browsers/).
- Mobile devices may have a hard time resizing images, and resizing may be fairly hard on the CPU. See [Don't Scale Images in HTML](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#no_scale) from Yahoo!'s performance guidelines.

As for storing images, Google gives this [advice](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=114016): "Consider structuring your directories so that similar images are saved together. For example, you might have one directory for thumbnails and another for full-size images". To me, this suggests that if you have the same filenames, Google will be clever enough to figure out which images are the resized versions.

I'm not sure how well search engines support it, but adding schema.org ImageObject markup may help search engines identify your images and thumbnails.